# Running Perl script with filename as arg

Tags: windows, perl

When working on my OSX box my perl script accepts my arguments with no complaints, on windows it doesnt.

Here is what im doing in cmd:

```
G:\perl>toxyz.pl -i "G:\perl\filename.log"
Error: invalid arguments.
G:\perl>
```

My perl code:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl -w -s
use File::Basename;

$logfile = $ARGV[0];

if(!$logfile || (!$s && !$i)){
    print STDERR "Error: invalid arguments.";
    exit(1);
}
```

This works fine on OSX.
What should i do?
Thanks.

Comment: what do you get when you do:  G:>\perl> perl toxyz.pl ...

Comment: Oh...it works...why does this work differently? It's already running the script cus my script outputs the invalid arg message.

Answer (score 6):

In your specific example:

```
$ARGV[0] = '-i'
$ARGV[1] = 'G:\perl\E-Garugamblin-1-1-irc.log'
```

See http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html#%40ARGV

Also, Windows requires command-line arguments to be surrounded by double-quotes, not single.

Finally, writing Perl without 'use strict; use warnings;' is a prescription for both frustration and in the worst case, disaster.

Comment: Yep...i just put single on accident in msg.

Answer (score -1):

You realize that the right side of your || is going to return true  since $s and $i aren't defined and will be seen as false.

I get this on my mac...

```
Name "main::s" used only once: possible typo at ./tmp.pl line 6.
Name "main::i" used only once: possible typo at ./tmp.pl line 6.
```

as such (!$s && !$i)  will be true, and so you're entering your 'error' block

Comment: No, if you put switches in the arg then in perl it collects them as var and sets the appropriate one true. so if i supply -i the $i = true

Comment: never used that feature. something new

Comment: In which version of Perl? Invoking 'perl -e "print $i ? 1 : 0" -- -i' using 5.10.1 on Windows will display '0' on the console.

Comment: Ahhh... that's what the -s switch does. For what it's worth, I think this is a very bad "feature" to use considering the distinct possibility your auto-vivified switch vars will trample over your main namespace. I'd stay FAR away from it.

Comment: The separate `-w` and `-s` options (as opposed to a combined `-ws`) is not reliably portable; you are not guaranteed more than about 32 bytes for the whole shebang line, nor more than a command and a single argument.  If you use `#!/usr/bin/env perl`, you can't supply other command-line options on the line reliably.